# how to map JS bytecode line number to sourcecode line number

Tags: javascript, v8

In order to protect JS source code, I use v8 to make cacheData and I run code by:

```
require('./main-window.jsc');
```

When code error happen, I got the error message:
[image]

The error just show error definition. Is there a way to help me locate the line? Just like add sourcemap to bytecode.
Thanks in advance.